# I installed the react-native-rate package and after this, the android build failed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using:

- "react-native": "0.69.5"
- "react-native-rate": "^1.2.12"
- android-gradle-plugin-version: 7.1.1
- gradle-version: 7.5

Issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1
```

Here are my Package.json dependencies and devDependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.6.5",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1289.0",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.4.4",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.5.1",
    "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.8.8",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.2.12",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.9.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-swipeable-list": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-track-player": "3.1",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.25.0",
    "react-native-wheel-color-picker": "^1.2.0",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
```

how to fix this issue?